# Kibana user - You do not have permission to access the requested page

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Kibana user - You do not have permission to access the requested page.

I created a role for few indices and assigned this role to the user. Still I get this error. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Please add more details on which page the user is not able to access

Answer (score 7):

The kibana_system is a built-in role used to connect to Elasticsearch.
It's not intended as a login to Kibana.
Login to Kibana using your elastic account and then create a new user and then use that one.

Comment: Login with elastic account says "Username or password is incorrect" for me. While I can execute healtcheck request via curl with the same username:password pair